# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 5000 ms

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka V 0.10.2 (8 Cores, 16 GB RAM). While executing the command

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
>   --describe --group

Sometimes I am getting this exception :

```
Exception in consumer group command (kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Request GROUP_COORDINATOR failed on brokers List(localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null))
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.sendAnyNode(AdminClient.scala:66)
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.findCoordinator(AdminClient.scala:71)
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.describeConsumerGroup(AdminClient.scala:157)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.collectGroupAssignment(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:399)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeGroup(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:148)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeGroup$(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:147)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.describeGroup(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:387)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:73)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
```

Am I missing something? How to fix it?

Comment: Did you enable the security? Besides, you'd better turn on DEBUG log level to see what went wrong there.

Comment: @amethystic No Security is not enabled. Got this error after enabling DEBUG for client side.Anything more I can do to fix this.

Comment: @amethystic: I observed one thing on restarting Kafka it works fine for few days. Then it starts throwing this error. I am not able to find which resource is becoming bottleneck